# Visual Studio Addin to convert Method into asynchronous Method with Result-Event

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, resharper, add-in

is there a Visual Studio Addin with which I can convert a method to an asynchronous method with an event for the result? I know that this is not very difficult but it would be a nice helper.

Resharper has not such feature?

something like that I want to convert

```
    public MyClass Start()
    {
            // lots of work
            return myObject;
    }
```

to that:

```
    public void Start()
    {
            // lots of work
            OnEndCreatingEvent(myObject);
    }

    internal delegate void EndCreatingEventHandler(MyClass myObject);
    public event EndCreatingEventHandler EndCreatingEvent;
    private void OnEndCreatingEvent(MyClass myObject)
    {
        if (EndCreatingEvent != null)
        {
            this.EndCreatingEvent(myObject);
        }
    }
```

Chris

Comment: You could certainly write a ReSharper plugin to do this. If interested, check out [this guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+7+Plugin+Development).